# corona sdk native.newWebView() dont work on windows build

Tags: video, webview, coronasdk

When using native.newWebView() on simulator I got:

```
WARNING: Web views are not supported in the simulator. Please build for device.
```

When using native.newWebView() in a windows build I got a black screen and no errors in Corona Output Viewer.

In both I tried a fresh project with the following main.lua file:

```
local webView = native.newWebView( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, 320, 480 )
webView:request( "http://www.coronalabs.com/" )
```

The documentation does not indicate incompatibility with this platforms. I'm running CoronaSDK-2016.2992.msi and Windows 10 Pro.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Corona [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/newWebView.html)

> Native web views are only(*) supported on Android, iOS, the Corona
>   Simulator for OS X, and OS X desktop apps
>
> (*) see below

From Corona [Blog](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2017/04/05/announcing-corona-labs-public-release-2017-3068/)

> Native web view objects are now available for both the Corona Simulator for Windows and Win32 desktop builds. It apply to version 2017.3068 and later.

Maybe [this](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/47924-nativenewwebview-for-windows-simulator-fix/) helps.

Comment: In fact, the last daily versions (after  2016.3011) support Web Views on Windows builds!

Comment: Link to [daily builds](https://developer.coronalabs.com/downloads/daily-builds/).